# Why this functions duplicate data when scroll down to bottom page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why this functions duplicate data when scroll down to bottom page ?

when scroll to bottom page sometime duplicate data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function(){       
       var height = $('#demoajax').height();
       var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
           var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();
           var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
           document.getElementById('check').value = page++;  
        if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) && (isload=='true')){    
            $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'aaa.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                   $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
                   $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
                   $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                   $('#demoajax').append(response);
                    }
                });
    }
    return false;   
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean sometimes the Ajax called more than one time, in that case you can busy flag. By default the busy flag set to false. Here is the code to do that

```
    var busy    =   false;

    if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) && (isload=='true'))
    {    
        if(busy)
            return; 

        busy = true;
        $('#loading').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'aaa.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#fid').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
                $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
                $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
                $('#demoajax').append(response);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                busy = false;
            }
        });
    }

    return false;   
});
```

});

I think this should solve the problem.
Thank You.